# Groovy CompileStatic with generic lists

Tags: generics, groovy

I have the following code in groovy:

```
class Test {
  List<Integer> yo(boolean x) {
    List<Integer> res = x ? [] : [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

It compiles nicely until I add `@CompileStatic` annotation to the class. Then compilation fails with

```
Test.groovy: 5: [Static type checking] - Incompatible generic argument types. Cannot assign java.util.List <? extends java.lang.Object> to: java.util.List <Integer>
 @ line 5, column 27.
       List<Integer> res = x ? [] : [1, 2, 3]
```

Is it really expected that Groovy cannot infer the generic type of that empty list `[]`?

Comment: `[]` has an iferred type `List<Object>` which is fine from my PoV. Same with `null`

Comment: In this particular case, having LHS of type `List<Integer>` I somehow expected `[]` to be of the same type... Because `List<Integer> l = []` does work...

Comment: This looks like Groovy bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to use generics at all. For me it compiles and runs good just like that:

```
List res = x ? [] : [1, 2, 3]
```

But if you still strongly need the generics try this:

```
List<Integer> res = x ? [] as List<Integer> : [1, 2, 3]
```